# Message queue system

Tags: c#, queue, message-queue

I am in the process of writing a message queue system.

My question is... Is it better to do this queue with files or in a database?

If I were to choose the database, it needs to check for new jobs every second and that just seems a bit of an overhead to me?

If it's files I guess you just constantly monitor the folder and execute based on that?

BR,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't [reinvent](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) [the](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx) [wheel](http://www.nservicebus.com/).

[Edit: updated for 2014, now linking to rabbit MQ as Ayende has moved on to making document databases and not message queues but then again RabbitMQ has come on. I would not be writing this but now posts need 30 characters so I need to blabber a bit.]

Answer (score 26):

I choose option "C" — use message queue that's already built in to Windows:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973860.aspx

Comment: This link is broken

Comment: @CoderDennis Updated.

Answer (score 5):

what are your criteria for deciding "Better"?  performance? scalability? reliability? cost?

The basic tradeoffs are:

Database - transactional support, integrity guarantees (via constraints), richer query support, *probably* will scale better (depending on implementation)

filesystem - cheaper, simpler, less moving parts (at least initially)

You may want to look at existing solutions first - MSMQ, SQL Server broker, open source libraries such as Rhino queues (http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/01/Rhino-Queues.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

How might want to look into [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Since you're not on meta often, I'm commenting here to let you know I responded to your post about this question on meta.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your requirements, but if you need to queue up multiple messages as one single group, you'll need some sort of transactional support. In that case the database is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Are you writing a message queue system because you want to write a message queue system; or is this just part of solving a bigger problem?

I would suggest not writing a new message queue system. You can use MSMQ or something else off the shelf.